# symfonyv3 & FOSRestBundlev2.1.1 : how to activate jsonp handling

Tags: jsonp, symfony, fosrestbundle

I've got this config.yml :

```
fos_rest:
    routing_loader:
        default_format: json
    view:
        mime_types:
            jsonp: ['application/javascript']
        formats:
            jsonp: true
        jsonp_handler:
            callback_param:       callback
            mime_type: application/javascript
```

When I call example.com/app_dev.php/api/users/1.jsonp?callback=toto, I've got this reponse in plain HTML :

> No route found for "GET /api/users/1.jsonp"

When I change my config file to :

```
fos_rest:
    routing_loader:
        default_format: json
    view:
        mime_types:
            jsonp: ['application/javascript']
        formats:
            jsonp: true
        jsonp_handler:
            callback_param:       callback
            mime_type: application/javascript
    format_listener:
            rules:
              - { path: '^/api', priorities: ['jsonp','json', 'xml', 'html'], fallback_format: json, prefer_extension: true }
```

the error is still the same, but json encoded.

If I modify `application/javascript` into `application/javascript+json`, chrome can't show the result

PS : everything work with the standards formats : html, xml, json

Answer (score 0):

This link shows a simpler configuration:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSRestBundle/2-the-view-layer.html#jsonp-custom-handler

So try:

```
# app/config/config.yml
fos_rest:
    view:
        jsonp_handler: ~
```

And see if that works.

Comment: I tried this one, but it also fail, the jsonp format isn't activated at all.
The V2.x version wich is the only one compatible with sympfony 3 is still in beta, so it is maybe "normal", but I can't make it works ...